# When loading the .pth weight file, where are they loaded when using cpu and cuda respectively?

Tags: linux

After loading the weight file, if it is loaded to the cpu version, then the weight file will exist in the process memory, and loaded to the cuda version, should the weight file be loaded into the process memory or the cuda video memory?
At present, I have found the weight binary file in the process memory by using /proc/pid/mem in the cpu version, but I don’t know where the weight file should appear in the cuda version?I want to know when the cuda version is used, will the weight file be loaded into the video memory of the graphics card or will it appear in the process memory like the cpu version? If it is loaded to video memory, how can I access it in Linux, using /proc/pid/mem and other similar methods.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.